# Multiple Bounce Roll for Percusion Rudiment using Musixtex

Tags: musixtex, musixper

I need to write the Multiple Bounce Roll symbol (like a Z letter with half note), but I couldn't find any symbol for that. Below is a basic code as reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}

%Description of the Multiple Bounce Roll
\begin{music}
    \largemusicsize
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startextract
    \Notes \hu a \en $\qquad$ {\Huge{$\Relbar$}}
    \Notes \zcharnote{-13}{\textbf\small \hspace*{0.15cm} L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R } \zcharnote{-9}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.01cm} R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L} \Ibbbu0aa7\qb0{aaa}\tbbbu0\qb0a\nbbbu0\qb0{aaa}\tqh0a\en
    \Notes \zcharnote{-13}{\textbf\small \hspace*{0.15cm} L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R } \zcharnote{-9}{\textbf\small \hspace*{-0.01cm} R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ R $\;\,$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L $\;\;$ L} \Ibbbu0aa7\qb0{aaa}\tbbbu0\qb0a\nbbbu0\qb0{aaa}\tqh0a\en
    \zendextract
\end{music}   


\end{document}
```

The expected output should be:

[image: Expected output]

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the command `\zcn{<note>}{<text>}`, where `<note>` determines the vertical placement and `<text>` can be anything, in your case, `\zcn{f}{\textbf{\textit{z}}}` looks about right.

[image]

The command `\zcn` will spill text to the right. There is also `\lcn` and `\ccn` for left and center respectively.

```
\Notes  \zhu a \zcn{f}{\textbf{\textit{z}}} \en
```